# date() method, "A non well formed numeric value encountered" does not want to format a date passed in $_POST

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I unfortunately can't use `DateTime()` as the server this project is on is running PHP v.5.2.

the line in question:

```
$aptnDate2 = date('Y-m-d', $_POST['nextAppointmentDate']);
```

throws the following error:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

so I var dump to make sure it's well formatted..

```
var_dump($_POST['nextAppointmentDate']);  

string(10) "12-16-2013"
```

The [php docs state](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) that it takes a timestamp not a string. but when I do:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['nextAppointmentDate']));
```

and then `var_dump` the result, I get this:

```
string(10) "1969-12-31"
```

**why can I not format a date with this date value and strtotime()?**

thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the documentation for [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas **if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.**

In your date string, you have `12-16-2013`. `16` isn't a valid month, and hence `strtotime()` returns `false`.

Since you can't use DateTime class, you could manually replace the `-` with `/` using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) to convert the date string into a format that `strtotime()` understands:

```
$date = '2-16-2013';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $date))); // => 2013-02-16
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that was it. I could have sworn dashes were acceptable, perhaps that is just with `DateTime()`? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @Prefix: If you pass an incorrectly formatted date string to `DateTime`, it will (usually) throw an exception. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for a list of accepted date formats. If you're using DateTime, then  **`DateTime::createFromFormat()`** is the way to go: https://eval.in/79189