# A non well formed numeric value encountered in php

Tags: php, numeric

I have this line of code in php

```
echo '<h1>' . fread($myfile,filesize("names.txt") . '</h1>');
```

when I try to run the code it says
*
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered 
*
can anyody help? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date() method, "A non well formed numeric value encountered" does not want to format a date passed in $\_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574465/date-method-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-does-not-want-to-fo)

Comment: you have not closed `fread` properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo.

```
echo '<h1>' . fread($myfile,filesize("names.txt")) . '</h1>';
```

The fread included `h1` after the filesize function.

Answer (score -2):

It is probably because names.txt does not exist. Try to

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('names.txt'))
```

in the line before to check that it indeed exists.