# A non well formed numeric value encountered show When to get current date and current time

Tags: php

I would like to get timestamp for current date and current time. I has searching for it today, but no luck, I got confused. I'm very basic in PHP btw :( The timestamp are correct, but I get that notice.

```
<?php
$current_time_and_date = mktime(date("h"), date("i"), date("sa"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
echo $current_time_and_date;
```

Result:

> **Notice**: A non well formed numeric value encountered in **C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php** on line **2**
>
> 1551814433

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574465/date-method-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-does-not-want-to-fo

Comment: This will give you current timestamp `<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>`

Comment: You need to use `date('H')` instead of `date('h')` and `date('s')` instead of `date('sa')` to fix your code but you should really just use `time()`

Comment: Forget about `mktime()` and the other awkward date & time function. Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. It is easier to use and it can also handle the timezone (handling the timezone using the old date & time functions is painful and not always possible).

Comment: Yeah It's look awkward in mktime XD I got new knowledge today, Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use `time()` function

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you for make my day! I'm glad that someone helping me.

Comment: if you got the result please accept my answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Please check 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

Exemple #4
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");