# I want to set the value of input datetype but it is not set

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.8

[image: Undesirable output]　Undesirable output
[image: Desired display] Desired display

Cannot set DB value for type = "time"

What is stored in the DB is 2:20
I want 2:20 on the edit screen

But as the picture comes out on the screen
How can I set the DB time to ?
**edit.blade.php**

```
<input id="estimated_work_time" type="time" name="estimated_work_time">{{$param->estimated_work_time}}
```

But I didn't get the results I wanted

**edit.blade.php**

```
<label for="estimated_work_time">Estimated work time</label><br>
<input id="estimated_work_time" type="time" name="estimated_work_time" value="{{$param->estimated_work_time}}"><br>
```

What should I do other than value?

It is displayed on the source code

I tried this too, but I get this error

```
<input id="estimated_work_time" type="time" name="estimated_work_time">{!!date('h:i a',strtotime($param->estimated_work_time)) !!} <br>
```

The error was this
**A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Comment: What is the format of `$param->estimated_work_time`? it must be `H:i:s` or `H:i`

Comment: shouldn't that be inside the `value` attribute

Comment: **Related:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Value

Comment: @ClaudioI Want to display data that already exists.

Comment: @Ghost What should I do?

Comment: @su3158 what's the raw output of `{{$param->estimated_work_time}}` ? If add `<p>{{$param->estimated_work_time}}</p>` what is the output?

Comment: @Script47 Thank you I saw it but it didn't work

Comment: @Claudio I didn't know how to send it and added it to the question

Comment: As asked by @Claudio, what is the format of your time? Dump that variable and give us the contents.

Comment: @Script47 The result of dd was "2:20"

Comment: again, as mentioned by @Claudio it must be either `H:i:s` or `H:i`.

Comment: @Script47 All right but I have no idea to do it

Comment: Try this while passing value to input based on dd()  `{!! date('H:i',$param->estimated_work_time) !!}`

Comment: @Vipertecpro　Thank you, I tried it but it was like this A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Can you show us how did you put it ?

Comment: Try this `{!! date('h:i a',strtotime($param->estimated_work_time)) !!}`

Comment: @Vipertecpro I tried and edited the results

Comment: Look if you want to discuss any error then you have to show us the error, you cant just it doesn't work, we all know it's not working, we need to know what exact error are you getting.

Comment: @Vipertecpro I forgot I was saved

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574514/4650866

Comment: I would recommend you to edit this question with more information, like what is the value saved in DB ?, what result are you expecting ?, what is the value you are getting in your blade file currently ?

Comment: @Vipertecpro Thank you I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright here is what I've gathered,

Left side is chrome and in right side is Mozilla
[image]

In both the cases you simply needs to pass the value to the input by default,so i think you can achieve your desired output just by placing value like this **XX:XX | 02:30**.

```
<input id="estimated_work_time" type="time" name="estimated_work_time" value="{{ date('h:i',strtotime($param->estimated_work_time)) }}">
```

Here is the test i make it to understand it better

```
<?php
   // If i run this
   echo date('h:i','2:30');
   // I will get this error PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered


   // So first you need to convert your date or time string into the proper format
   echo date('h:i',strtotime('2:30'));
   // this will return output this : 02:30
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for type time value should be  2:35 AM   if you want 2:20 use other type and some php script

Comment: To be more precise , this is how you create 12 hours format in php  laravel `date('h:i:s a m/d/Y', strtotime($date))` so i think this `{!! date('h:i a',strtotime($param->estimated_work_time)) !!}`  will work

Comment: I can't display it from DB yet

Comment: i am not going to create 12 hours format, i thought its DB value is estimated time just like 35 hours i mean it is not time it is just subtraction of two different time is it right